# How to change icons of last page and first page in TablePagination component of material-ui react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pagination, icons

In TablePagination component of material ui react, there is a option to show or hide last page and first page buttons, but how can we change them if I want to use another icon in place of default ones. Is there any way or I have to customize pagination using usePagination?
I am talking about below buttons. I want to replace it with another icon. Also I want to change next and previous buttons to text saying "Next" and "Previous".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to change the icons via a simple prop. I'd just write a custom `TablePaginationActions`. This component is specifically with regards to the 4 buttons in MUI v5 (only 2 buttons in MUI v4).

You can refer to [this link](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/TablePagination/TablePaginationActions.js) to check out the implementation of that component. Here are the steps to craete and use a custom one:

1. Make a new `.js` for your custom version
2. Copy/paste the contents of that link
3. Update the imports as per your MUI version (@mui/... or $material-ui/...)
4. Update the class name (recommended at least). These would be the declaration, the propTypes, and the export.
5. Update any items that might have their name changed by step #3 (eg. KeyboardArrowLeft might be KeyboardArrowLeftIcon now)
6. If you are in v4, add the first/last buttons with the appropriate logic (first page button would be `onPageChange(event, 0);` whilst the last page button would be `onPageChange(event, Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1);` For this use case, simply update the icon you wish to use (`<LastPageIcon />` and `<FirstPageIcon />`)
7. In your file that has the `TablePagination`, import the new custom component
8. In your TablePagination component, add the prop `ActionsComponent={CustomTablePaginationActions}` where `CustomTablePaginationActions` is the name you set in #4.

This would ensure that by default, it will use what is standard, but you can always import and specify your custom component where appropriate.